# JavaFX lot of similar MouseEvents for ImageViews

Tags: java, javafx

Hi I have problem with huge amount of similar drag and drop events for images, which i move with label to other image views.

Example of code:

```
//drag and drope for imageview01
@FXML
private void handleDragDetected1(MouseEvent event) {
      Dragboard db = imageview01.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
      ClipboardContent cb = new ClipboardContent();
      cb.putImage(imageview01.getImage());
      cb.putString(imageview01_label.getText());
      db.setContent(cb);
      System.out.println("Picture 1 is draged");
}
...
...
//drag and drope for imageview100
@FXML
private void handleDragDetected100(MouseEvent event) {
     ...
     ...
}
```

Is there any solution to make code shorten ?

Comment: Don't wire a hundred event handlers up via FXML.  Instead, just use a loop in code.

Comment: How this loop look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign the `Label`s as `userData` of the corresponding `ImageView`s which allows you to use the event source to retrieve the `Label` and therefore allows you to use the same event handler for all `ImageView`s.

The following example uses a `Button` and the `onMouseClicked` event for simplicity, but the same approach works for your problem too:

#### FXML

```xml
<Label text="Hello World" fx:id="label1"/>
<Button text="Print Label 1" onMouseClicked="#click" userData="$label1"/>
```

#### Controller

```
@FXML
private void click(MouseEvent event) {
    // retrieve the node the event occured on
    Button btn = (Button) event.getSource();

    // retrieve Label associated with event source
    Label label = (Label) btn.getUserData();

    // now we've got all info we need without using any field of the controller
    System.out.println(label.getText());
}
```

(You do not even need a `label1` field in the controller.)

Comment: Thanks. How it will be in FXML and Contoller if i want  setUserdata for label?

Comment: @MarekKrištof Please clarify what you mean. What is *it*`? Why use `setUserData` of the label and what is the value you want to set?

Comment: So I have imageview on drag event whitch i assign userdata (label)
next ia have drop event where i have also imageview, to this imageview i set image from drag event and also i have label..and this specific label whitch i need to assign to specific imegaview